# Late Binding vs. Polymorphism - what is the difference?

Tags: oop, polymorphism, late-binding

I've seen both used interchangebly but do they really mean the same? From my understanding, Polymorphism stretches the fact that you could exchange an instance of a class by an instance of a subclass, and Late Binding means that when you call a method of an instance, the type decides which method (subclass/superclass) gets called.

Comment: It should be noted that polymorphism is not limited to inheritance hierarchies -- two unrelated classes that implement a common interface can be used polymorphically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia has a very nice article about this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming

Summary: Late binding is a way to implement polymorphism.

Comment: Downvoted because of the lack of an answer ON StackOverflow and average (at best) quality of the linked material. If you summarize the article on SO I will gladly remove my downvote.